# Inheriting properties from an imported CSS file

Tags: html, css

I'm using the [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome) for some button icons. It has a lot of different icons, and you reference them so:

```
<a href="#" class="fa-home"></a>
```

However, I'd like to wrap this into my own CSS property (basically, for simpler naming), like:

```
.home-button {
  <!-- return "fa-home" property here -->
}
```

One of Font Awesome's examples for using bordered fonts is: `<i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-3x fa-pull-left fa-border"></i>`

So effectively I want to wrap these different options into my own css property names, something like `'.icon-button-bordered'`, and somehow import the Font Awesome class.

Is it possible to do something like this in CSS?

Comment: why not to use `class="fa-home home-button"`?

Comment: use css compiler less or sass for it. best way is @Pangloss suggestion

Comment: the only way to achieve what you want from a style sheet point of view is to cut and paste the corresponding font awesome style into your own style (or go through the font awesome style sheet and rename all their classes with your classes).  Seems a bit of hassle for a "simpler name" and I would have thought `fa-home` is simpler than `home-button`

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by using CSS preprocessors. For example, mixins feature in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins) or extend feature in [LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature) and [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).